# How to read NextActivityDefinitions of a TridionActivityDefinitionData using Core Service?

Tags: 2011, core-service, workflow

I need to get the next activity definitions on a `TridionActivityDefinitionData` object using Core Service in Tridion 2011 SP1. My activity definition object represents an automatic activity with 2 next activities.

My problem is that using the code below, the property `NextActivityDefinitions` is null:

```
TridionActivityDefinitionData tridionActivityDefinition =
    client.Read("tcm:21-443-131088", readOptions) as TridionActivityDefinitionData;
Console.WriteLine(tridionActivityDefinition.NextActivityDefinitions);
```

I tried with simple readOptions:

```
ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions()
```

but also with other flags. Still I get back null.

```
readOptions.LoadFlags = LoadFlags.Expanded | LoadFlags.IncludeAllowedActions |
    LoadFlags.KeywordXlinks | LoadFlags.WebDavUrls;
```

API doc says:

> “Field Value: Will be null if the Activity Definition is read stand-alone. In the context of a Process Definition it will be set.
>   The collection should be empty if this represents the last activity or it should contain exactly one activity, unless this represents a decision. Note that the next activity should be identified (linked) by title, not by Id.”

So my question is, how do I read the Activity Definition in context of a Process Definition using Core Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably

> Will be null if the Activity Definition is read stand-alone. In the context of a Process Definition it will be set

is not quite clear. This mean, that when you read ActivityDefinition only basic data will be read, but if you read ProcessDefinition - you will get all data (PD data, activities Data + nextActivities).

So, you need something like this:

```
var ad = (TridionActivityDefinitionData)client.Read("tcm:98-373-131088", 
                                                                  _defaultReadOptions);
var pd = (TridionProcessDefinitionData)client.Read(ad.ProcessDefinition.IdRef, 
                                                                  _defaultReadOptions);
var resultActivity = (TridionActivityDefinitionData)pd.ActivityDefinitions
                                                      .First(x => x.Title == ad.Title);
```

Btw, I've tried on the current Tridion version (2013SP1) your code and it already works(for next activity only id and title are read).

Comment: Indeed it works (also in Tridion 2011). I'll accept this answer. Thanks for the code sample.

Comment: I meant, that your code (in top message) works now in 2013 SP1 - behaviour was changed and NextActivityDefinitions are read on reading AD.